# WeChat oauth 2 doesn't work - how to fix?

Tags: oauth, wechat

I'm trying to setup Wechat oauth login.
I have verified international account ("subscription" type), but an example from documentation doesn't work for my appid
https://open.weixin.qq.com/connect/qrconnect?appid=wx13243a5b6496168e&redirect_uri=http://foo.bar/baz&response_type=code&scope=snsapi_login

> Scope 参数错误或没有 Scope 权限

I guess this may be because of "subscription" type, but there were no such options during a registration process.

What should I do to enable WeChat oauth for my site?

Comment: Have you the set the verification domain?

Comment: @Thennarasan I have no idea where can I do that. There is no such option, can you explain?

Comment: Go through this like http://blog.csdn.net/yiluoak_47/article/details/48249979 here you can see with screenshots

Comment: @Thennarasan Thanks for the link. But I have nothing similar to "OAuth option" in my menu. I think that's because I have registered as an International user (for admin.wechat.com) and don't have access to mp.weixin.qq.com

Comment: Yep, you have use mp.weixin.qq.com and create a account. or you can use mp.weixin.qq.com sandbox

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who tries to do the OAuth with wechat in swift, you can follow [this link](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/oplatform/en/Mobile_App/Access_Guide/iOS.html) here to start with SDK integration, then [this link](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/oplatform/en/Mobile_App/WeChat_Login/Development_Guide.html) to integrate OAuth. i post it here because the above link you provided has expired.

the error message above basically means you didn't specify the scope of your request. the second link has it.

```
// Build a SendAuthReq structure
    SendAuthReq* req =[[[SendAuthReq alloc]init]autorelease];
    req.scope = @"snsapi_userinfo";
    req.state = @"123";
    // The third party sends a SendAuthReq message structure to the Weixin platform.
    [WXApi sendReq:req];
```